# Difference between @MapKey, @MapKeyColumn and @MapKeyJoinColumn in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

As per [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html), there are multiple annotations available if we want to use Map as an association between our entities. The doc says:

> Alternatively the map key is mapped to a dedicated column or columns.
>   In order to customize the mapping use one of the following
>   annotations:
>
> @MapKeyColumn if the map key is a basic type. If you don't specify the
>   column name, the name of the property followed by underscore followed
>   by KEY is used (for example orders_KEY). @MapKeyEnumerated /
>   @MapKeyTemporal if the map key type is respectively an enum or a Date.
>   @MapKeyJoinColumn/@MapKeyJoinColumns if the map key type is another
>   entity. @AttributeOverride/@AttributeOverrides when the map key is a
>   embeddable object. Use key. as a prefix for your embeddable object
>   property names. You can also use @MapKeyClass to define the type of
>   the key if you don't use generics.

By doing some examples I am able to understand that @MapKey is just used to map the key to a property of target entity and this key is used only for fetching records. @MapKeyColumn is used to map the key to a property of target entity and this key is used to save as well as fetching records. Please let me know if this is correct?

Also please let me know when I need to use @MapKeyJoinColumn/@MapKeyJoinColumns & @MapKeyEnumerated / @MapKeyTemporal

Thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you use a `Map` you always need to associate at least two entities. Let's say we have an `Owner` entity that relates to the `Car` entity (`Car` has a FK to `Owner`).

So, the `Owner` will have a `Map` of `Car(s)`:

```
Map<X, Car>
```

### `@MapKey`

The `@MapKey` will give you the `Car's` property used to group a `Car` to its `Owner`. For instance, if we have a `vin` (Vehicle Identification Number) property in `Car`, we could use it as the `carMap` key:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    @MapKey(name = "vin")
    private Map<String, Car> carMap;
}

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;

    private String vin;

}
```

### `@MapKeyEnumerated`

The `@MapKeyEnumerated` will use an Enum from `Car`, like `WheelDrive`:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<WheelDrive, Car> carMap;
}

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;

    @Column(name = "wheelDrive")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private WheelDrive wheelDrive;

}

public enum WheelDrive {
    2WD, 
    4WD;             
}
```

This will group cars by their WheelDrive type.

### `@MapKeyTemporal`

The `@MapKeyTemporal` will use a `Date`/`Calendar` field for grouping, like `createdOn`.

```
@Entity
public class Owner {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    @MapKeyTemporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Map<Date, Car> carMap;
}

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="created_on")
    private Calendar createdOn;         
}
```

### `@MapKeyJoinColumn`

The `@MapKeyJoinColumn` requires a third entity, like `Manufacturer` so that you have an association from `Owner` to `Car` and car has also an association to a `Manufacturer`, so that you can group all `Owner's` `Cars` by `Manufacturer`:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id")
    private Map<Manufacturer, Car> carMap;
}

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;          
}

@Entity
public class Manufacturer {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, if possible can you please take a look at my other post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664452/components-as-composite-identifiers-in-hibernate/ Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: I'll take a look tonight

Comment: I'd have a similar question. For some reason `@MapKey` does not give me the expected result. Could you take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235462/transitive-mapping-to-child-entity ? ^^

Comment: @VladMihalcea  Currently I'm working on migration from `hibernate 3.3.2` to `hibernate 4.3.11`. How to migrate `@MapKey` cause MapKey cannot be resolved to a type in `hiberante4`

Comment: Could u compare @MapKeyType as well, please? I found little information on the Internet

Comment: It's quite urgent, so could you plz take a look at this similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307329/hibernate-4-what-should-replace-deprecated-mapkey-to-map-a-map-collection-whi

Comment: I'm on vacation. I'll see when I get back.

Comment: There is a colon at the end of paragraph 1; was there once an example, because there is no code in the answer that shows the difference between MapKey and MapKeyColumn, which is I think the OP's main question, and yet the question is considered as answered.

Comment: Now, it does. Check out the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of using @MapKey with @OneToMany with a composite @IdClass. It's obviously not the only way to accomplish the objective here, but I felt this was the most maintainable.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template_categories")
@IdClass(TemplateCategoryId.class)
public class TemplateCategory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    long orgId;
    @Id
    long templateId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = TemplateEntry.class)
    @JoinColumns( {
        @JoinColumn(name = "orgId",  referencedColumnName = "orgId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "templateId",  referencedColumnName = "templateId")
        }
    )
    @MapKey(name="key")
    private Map<String, TemplateEntry> keyMap;
```

source code:
https://github.com/in-the-keyhole/jpa-entity-map-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/mapkey/entity/TemplateCategory.java