# Components as composite identifiers in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, composite-key

I am following [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-compositeid) and trying to implement the example given for section `9.4. Components as composite identifiers` but facing issues on how to implement it.

Here is what I have done:

My entity classes:

`Order.java`

```
public class Order {
    private int id;
    private Set<OrderLine> lines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
   // Setters & Getters
}
```

`OrderLine.java`

```
public class OrderLine {
    private OrderLineId id;
    private String name;
    private Order order;
   // Setters & Getters
}
```

`OrderLineId.java`

```
public class OrderLineId implements Serializable{
    private int lineId;
    private int orderId;
    private int customerId;
   // Setters & Getters
}
```

My mapping file which is having issues:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Order" table="TEST_Order">
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <set name="lines" cascade="all">
         <key column="orderId"/>
         <one-to-many class="OrderLine"/>
      </set>
   </class>

<class name="OrderLine" table="TEST_OrderLine">
    <composite-id name="id" class="OrderLineId">
        <key-property name="lineId"/>
        <key-property name="orderId"/>
        <key-property name="customerId"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="name"/>

    <many-to-one name="order" class="Order"
            insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="orderId"/>
        <column name="customerId"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I am trying to create a session factory which parses this mapping file, I am getting an exception saying:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_89b4nqt5l2n6tfd1d5tq0ill0:TEST_OrderLine [orderId,customerId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (TEST_Order [id])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1739)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
```

Can someone please help me how to implement the example given in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OrderLine needs to reference the Order PK, which is not a composite key.

It means the many-to-one must be:

```
<many-to-one name="order" class="Order"
        insert="false" update="false">
    <column name="orderId"/>
</many-to-one>
```

The orderId is the FK to Order.id.

Then the one-to-many side will become:

```
<set name="lines" cascade="all">
    <key>
        <column name="orderId"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="OrderLine"/>
</set>
```

So even if the OrderLine has a composite-key, the reference is made after Order.id, which is a simple key.

If you want to map other association to OrderLine, like OrderLineProduct then you'll need to use the composite-key to map the association between the parent (OrderLine) and the child (OrderLineProduct), so that OrderLineProduct has a composite-foreign-key back to OrderLine.

Comment: Hi Vlad, Thanks a lot for responding. I made changes to my hbm file as per your suggestions but I am still getting same exception.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I was confused by that composite-key but the one-Order-to-many-OrderLine association needs only a simple key (the Order.id).

Comment: Following your answer has fixed my issue. Based on your explanation I am  clear on the issue now so I tried having same mapping file mentioned in my question and created a composite Id for my `Order` entity and even that worked without issues now. Thanks a lot Vlad.

Answer (score 0):

In both the table hbm mapping you should have same no. of column ,what you are using to make composite.You need to add these 3 column in TEST_Oder.
Example to follow :

```
<many-to-one name="orderLine" class="OrderLine">
<column name="lineId"/>
<column name="orderId"/>
<column name="customerId"/>
</many-to-one>
```

Refer same [URL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-compositeid)

Comment: Now I started getting exception as `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_d3m49ikqc9585v3uro8r58a8q:TEST_OrderLine [lineId,orderId,customerId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (TEST_Order [id])`

Comment: @Chaitanya its a problem of column mapping only, you need to work out more on it , because it is a configuration problem kind.

Comment: yes, that is what I was not able to figure out and seeking help in SO