# How to use a child association property as a Map key in JPA parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I'm having two entities `Car` and `CarDescription` where `CarDescription` is depending on another foreign key from the table `Language`.

What I' trying to accomplish is to have a `HashMap` in `Car` such that whenever I'm having a `Car` entity-object I am able to access all descriptions from the language id.

Entity **Car.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Car")
public class Car extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5041816842632017838L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="car")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "language_ID")
    // @MapKey(name = "language") // does not work either 
    private Map<Long, CarDescription> carDescription = new HashMap<>(0);
}
```

Entity **CarDescription.java**

```
@Entity
@Table( name="car_description",
        uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"language_id", "name"}) 
        }
)
public class CarDescription extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2840651722666001938L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Car car;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    private Language language;

    // ..
}
```

Entity **Language.java**

```
@Entity
public class Language implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3968717758435500381L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    // ..
}
```

The problem I am having is that the mapping gives me a map from each `CarDescription.id` to `CarDescription`.

How can I accomplish a correct mapping?

Comment: Why does `@MapKey(name = "language")` not suit you?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic It's the same.. I'm always getting a map `CarDescription.id -> CarDescription` but what I want is `Language.id -> CarDescription`. I don't know but `@MapKey(name = "language")` does not work.. :/

Comment: It seems to be ignored. Are imports good, is it an annotation from `javax.persistence`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Yes, it's from `javax.persistence`. Another thing I've tried is `@MapKeyColumn (name = "language_ID")` but that didn't work either but in that case the map is just empty .. No idea what's not working here

Comment: You tried with `@MapKeyColumn` together with `@MapKey` or without it?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic without it. Would I have to use both? I tried it due to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-indexed) that says: "*@MapKeyColumn if the map key is a basic type. If you don't specify the column name, the name of the property followed by underscore followed by KEY is used (for example orders_KEY).*"

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Hmm.. I just don't get it. It should work that way ..

Comment: Your one-to-many association is wrong, it should be `mappedBy = "car"`. Then it should work with @MapKeyColumn.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I've now tried `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car") @MapKeyColumn (name = "language_ID")` but the map is here still empty :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CarDescription` you need to add the `languageId` property:

```
@Column(name = "language_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long languageId;

@NotNull
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
private Language language;

public void setLanguage(Language language) {
    this.languageId = language.getId();
    this.language = language;
}
```

Then you can use it in the `Car` entity like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="car")
@MapKey(name = "languageId")
private Map<Long, CarDescription> carDescription = new HashMap<>(0);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for stopping by! :) Well, I've tried that but now I'm getting  `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException` "*a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session*"  on `CarDescription`. Can't get around it :/

Comment: That's something completely unrelated to the current question. That can happen when you call `Session.saveOrUpdate(entity)` when the entity is already associated to the current Session. You need to review your persistence logic thoroughly.

Comment: It seems that the problem does come from `@MapsId`. The creation statement is now giving me `primary key (language_ID)` which won't work. Is there no other way to create this mapping?

Comment: Right, that only works for identifiers. I changed the answer to using `insertable = false, updatable = false`. Check the updated version.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much I don't know if I would have solved that ever by myself! Hibernate has a ridiculously flat learning curve.. ^^

Comment: Great trick! However, why did it not work with `@MapKeyColumn`?

Comment: It should have worked with `@MapKeyColumn` as you suggested, so it must have failed because of some Hibernate bug. Could you fill a JIRA issue?

Comment: Yes, I will try to reproduce it in a test case and create a jira issue. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `@MapKeyJoinColumn ` be used? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439813/difference-between-mapkey-mapkeycolumn-and-mapkeyjoincolumn-in-jpa-and-hiber#25447741