# How to create relationships in entities correctly

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

The entity describing the machine

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine")
public class Machine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;      
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "machine_node", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "machine_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "node_id"))
    private List<NodeMachine> nodeMachines = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The entity describing the part/node

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node_machine")
public class NodeMachine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Several parts are installed on each machine (nodeMachines list), and each part can be installed on different machines, so ManyToMany was added.

For example, a wheel can be mounted on a motorcycle or a car. A motorcycle can have two wheels, and a car can have four.

I will describe in more detail what is in the tables. I must say right away that the example is not very successful, just for understanding. In the Machine table we have 100 M motorcycles (1-100) and 100 C cars (1-100). And there is only one entry in the NodeMachine table - the K1 wheel, which is suitable for all one hundred motorcycles and for all one hundred cars. From this, there is no way to determine how many wheels each motorcycle and each car should have. Therefore, I believe that there should be a third table where the number of wheels is indicated for each car and motorcycles. And I think it's too redundant to keep 200 records of wheels for motorcycles and 400 records for cars in the table.

Each part is installed on a specific machine in a certain number.
I want to get the number of nodes installed in a particular machine by knowing the node and machine name.
To do this, you will have to create another count_machine_node table with the fields

```
- machine_id
- node_id
- count
```

I understand that you will have to create a new entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node_machine")
public class CountNodeMachine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long machine_id;
    private Long node_id;
    private Integer count;
}
```

But what connections do you need to register in these entities?

How to link these three tables correctly?

And do I need to create a CountNodeMachine entity?

Answer (score 7):

Please comment if this serves the purpose.

### Machine entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine")
public class Machine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="machineId")
    List<MachinePartCount> count;
```

### Part entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "part")
public class Part {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="partId")
    List<MachinePartCount> count;
```

### Relation entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="machine_part")
@IdClass(MachinePartCountPK.class)
public class MachinePartCount {
    
    
    @Id
    private Integer machineId;
    
    @Id
    private Integer partId;
        
    private Integer count;
```

### Composite Key

```
@Embeddable
public class MachinePartCountPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer machineId;
    
    private Integer partId;
```

### output:

```
    **machineService.findAll()**
    getAllMachines: [Machine [id=1, name=m1, count=[MachinePartCount [machineId=1, partId=1, count=2]]], Machine [id=2, name=m2, count=[MachinePartCount [machineId=2, partId=102, count=4]]]]
    
    **partService.findAll()**
    getAllParts: [Part [id=1, name=p100, count=[MachinePartCount [machineId=1, partId=1, count=2]]], Part [id=102, name=p10, count=[MachinePartCount [machineId=2, partId=102, count=4]]]]

    **machinePartCountService.findAll()**
    getmachinePartEntries: [MachinePartCount [machineId=1, partId=1, count=2], MachinePartCount [machineId=2, partId=102, count=4]]
```

Data in tables:
machine table:
[machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjX4i.png)
part table:
[part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLNjz.png)
machine_part table:
[machine_part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNqhW.png)

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to better explain what you changes, why this will fix the issue and how ?

Comment: And where are the connections between Machine and Part?

Answer (score 4):

I always suggest to start development from the Java side. So, it might be something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine")
public class Machine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // Список узлов машины
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<NodeMachine, Integer> nodeMachines = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Also, check my [Hibernate articles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020294/andriy-slobodyanyk?tab=profile) (Russian and English versions)

Comment: It seems to me that this method is not very suitable. We have an M1 motorcycle that can have two K wheels and a C1 car that can have four K wheels. According to this method, I will have two entries K(1-2) for M1 and four entries K (3-6) for C1 in the NodeMachine table.

Comment: But this is redundant information. And when there are 100 motorcycles in the table, then 200 wheel records will have to be stored for them? In NodeMachine there will be only one entry K1, which is suitable for both M1 and C1 and possibly for the other 100 motorcycles. But in this case, your method will not work. This example is conditional, just for demonstration.

Comment: Your comments seem to be relevant to the solution below! My suggestion is to have 3 tables: the 1st for machine, the 2nd for nodeMachine and the 3rd for count of the nodes per the machine. But instead of creating the third entity or creating redundant repository methods I'm suggesting to hide this under the Map. In other words, my point is to create convenient Java domain model beforehand and only afterwards store it to the DB (actually, Hibernate will do it for you, just put some annotations)

Comment: After all, the third table will be created. Okay, I'll check your option. If it works, then this is what I need!

Comment: Your code is working. That's just I can't get a list of Machines from the NodeMachine table. It turns out that the ManyToMany annotation should be added to the NodeMachine entity. But now, in the Machine entity, ElementCollection is used instead of ManyToMany. I do not know how to map ManyToMany from NodeMachine to ElementCollection from Machine?

Comment: First, I would suggest to check it you really need to have NodeMachine to be aware of Machine. If, so you may use the very same joining table and adjust the map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439813/difference-between-mapkey-mapkeycolumn-and-mapkeyjoincolumn-in-jpa-and-hiber

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the third entity, as you can do the sql query, or select machine by name, filter it's `nodeMachines` list and count the result.

For example, using the repository, like [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) you can select machine by id, or a list of machines by name, and then just filter it's(their's) node lists by name and count.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MachineRepository extends CrudRepository<Machine, Long> {   
  List<Machine> findByName(String lastName);
}
```

And somewhere in your code:

```
@Autowired
private MachineRepository machineRepository;

public int countNodesInMachine(String machineName, String nodeName) {
    return machineRepository.findByName(machineName).stream()
        .flatMap(machine -> machine.getNodeMachines().stream())
        .filter(node -> node.getName().equals(nodeName))
        .count();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this has confused you. I didn't say that a node can only be installed on one machine. I gave an example for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Anyway you probably don't need the third entity. You can use simple query or repository to select what you need.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it. What connections should be specified.

Comment: This option is also not suitable, there is also a count of the number of records. I described the situation in detail in the bottom answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can create a counter in the NodeMachine entity. This is economical in terms of occupied space in the database, but not true in terms of object orientation. Using the CountNodeMachine entity is not economical at all because a table is wasted to hold a number. I think you need a wrapper class that has NodeMachine and its counts. and use List of this to Machine Entity.

Comment: It won't work that way. I described everything in detail. You understand that there will be one NodeMachine entry, and it can have as many count fields as you like (5 or 10 or 100). Theoretically, it can be different for each machine. And how do you get an arbitrary number of counters for each NodeMachine record here?

Answer (score 0):

If I get from the above example,
You can do is create a third entity namely as `Categories`.

As you have a machine specific category, like Motorcycles or Car.
They have a specific set of wheels.

You can map that in this third table and create relation with the Machine.

`Categores

id| category| wheels| othernodes

1 | Car     | 4     | 1

2 | Bike    | 2     | 3`

and so on, you just will have to find the category and node from the machine table and get the count easily, also you can add new nodes for the same.

The only downside is that you machine will be specific to **Category**.