# In what container should @OneToMany Entity be stored in this example?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have `Order` entity, each order has a list of `Dish` entity.

*Only important part showed for brevity.*

```
    @Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "orders")
@ToString
public class Order {
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "order",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Dish> dishes;
}
```

My front sends me a `Hashmap` of `dish.id` and quantity of this dish ordered.

To convert it to Order entity I have to add the same dish to list **times it was ordered**.
For example. if order has 5 dishes of id 1, I fetch id 1 and add it 5 times to list, then - save order.

To display this again in front - I use Collections.frequency to convert the Order back to Hashmap.

Should I convert my relationship container to hashmap? I've heard that I should avoid using hashmaps in Hibernate.

Comment: I’ve already answered to the pretty same question, have a look, please https://stackoverflow.com/a/70184988/5020294

Comment: Also, it worths to pay your attention that Dish equals() and hashCode should be implemented in the correct way https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/