# Hibernate: CascadeType on ManyToMany relation with extra column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I got two entities, `Student` and `Course`. One `Student` can have many `Course` and one `Course` can have many `Student`. Normally, I would have Hibernate generate a jointable like this:

```java
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
            name="studentCourseJoinTable", 
            joinColumns= {
                    @JoinColumn(
                            name="studentId", 
                            referencedColumnName="studentId"
                            ) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns= {
                    @JoinColumn(
                            name="courseId", 
                            referencedColumnName="courseId")
                    }
            )
private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

Problem is, that I need to store the *grade* of the student in this course. For the sake of simplicity, lets say it is just a normal integer value. Without Hibernate, I'd build a simple jointable with a extra column for the grade value, something like this:

```
+-----------+----------+-------+
| studentId | courseId | grade |
+-----------+----------+-------+
|         1 |        1 |     1 |
|         1 |        2 |     2 |
|         2 |        1 |     5 |
|         2 |        3 |     6 |
+-----------+----------+-------+
```

So I followed [this guide in the JPA Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns) and set it up like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable
{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    private List<StudentCourse> courses = new ArrayList<StudentCourse>();
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Course implements Serializable
{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="course")
    private List<StudentCourse> courses = new ArrayList<StudentCourse>();
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(StudentCourse.class)
public class StudentCourse implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private int studentId;
    
    @Id
    private int courseId;
    
    private int grade;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="studentId", referencedColumnName="studentId")
    private Student student;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="courseId", referencedColumnName="courseId")
    private Course course;
    ...
}
```

It is ugly, but it works how it should work.

Now, the problem: Cascading. It's no problem with the `@ManyToMany` relation in the first example (I got another relation within `Student`, but it doesn't matter for this problem).

What I want is that if I delete a `Student`, the corresponding rows in the `StudentCourse` table gets also dropped, and the other way around: If I delete a `Course`, the corresponding rows should also get dropped. But I don't get

1. where to put the `cascade = CascadeType.XY`
2. *which* type of the cascade

I tried to use `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` on both the `Student` and the `Course`, but this just leads to this if I delete a Student:

```
2022-02-09T22:33:59.222+0100  ERROR  integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FKD0KC5NKFVH9A0DIFGUI129HFC table: STUDENTCOURSES
```

Comment: I've recently answered the similar question, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184043/how-to-create-relationships-in-entities-correctly/70184988#70184988

Comment: Thank you, this works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, always I create the foreign keys directly in the database with the CASCADE option. Not be if it is a valid option for you.